# SerializationException on null character in C# DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json

I want to deserialize a stream of bytes in a byte[] array in C#. The byte[] array is 8196 bytes long and gets its information from a TCP/IP connection.

When I give that array to the ReadObject method of System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer, it throws me a SerializationException with the message "Encountered unexpected character '\0'".

How could I fix this?

Comment: The problem isn't solved, but I have made a work-around by creating a byte[] array that exactly matches the size of the received data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you reading the string? Generally, the '\0' error points to an encoding problem. The byte stream could use a particular type of encoding, and you're either to force an encoding of your own -- or you're deserializing in such a way that a particular encoding inconsistent with the actual encoding of the stream is being assumed.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/b80c9aa7-a3d1-4aa0-b61a-35363cbc177e describes a situation where the replacement of the following line of code:

```
s = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(ms.GetBuffer());
```

with:

```
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

fixed the problem. Perhaps something similar applies to your situation as well?

Comment: I create the byte array myself from a stream from a TCP/IP connection. When I encounter a byte that ends my part of the protocol, I insert a \0 character myself. I come from a C-background, so I didn't realise that C# strings can have \0 characters in them.